# How can I change the placement of a point that has automatically been placed by LaTex?

Tags: tkz-collection, tkz-euclide

I used the command `\tkzGetPoint{a}` to make the angle bisector of the `ABC` angle.  However, the point `a` gets placed much further below the triangle than I would like and that causes there to be a large space between the shape and my text underneath it. How can I fix this problem? Here is my work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\center 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below,left](A)
    \tkzDefPoint(2.25,3.320718914){B}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
    \tkzDefPoint(6,0){C}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below,right](C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
    \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](a)
    \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{D}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){E}
    \tkzDrawSegment(E,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{12}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](12)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{15}
    \tkzLabelPoints[right=0.1cm](15)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,C) \tkzGetPoint{18}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below=0.4cm](18)
    \end{tikzpicture}

$\angle{ACD}=\angle{BCD}=\frac{\angle{ACB}}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I labelled the point *a* just so that it can be seen.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a bounding box like

```
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.5,xmax=6.7,ymin=-0.7,ymax=3.5]
```

with suitable coordinates and then clip with some padding

```
\tkzClip[space=.25]
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5,xmax=6.7,ymin=-0.7,ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip[space=.25]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below,left](A)
    \tkzDefPoint(2.25,3.320718914){B}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
    \tkzDefPoint(6,0){C}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below,right](C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
    \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
    %\tkzLabelPoints[left](a)
    \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{D}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){E}
    \tkzDrawSegment(E,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{12}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](12)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{15}
    \tkzLabelPoints[right=0.1cm](15)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,C) \tkzGetPoint{18}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below=0.4cm](18)
    \end{tikzpicture}

$\angle{ACD}=\angle{BCD}=\frac{\angle{ACB}}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]